# Fetch min and max values in the same row using group by

Tags: sqlite

The first thing is my English is basic. Sorry.
Second thing, and the most important here: I can't find the way to do a simple query. My table is like this:

> ```
> ------------------------------------------
> id_det_iti | id_iti | orden_iti| id_ciudad
> --------------------------------------------
> 1          | 1      | 1        | 374      
> 2          | 1      | 2        | 25
> 3          | 1      | 3        | 241
> 4          | 2      | 1        | 34      
> 5          | 2      | 2        | 22
> 6          | 2      | 3        | 352
> 7          | 2      | 4        | 17
> --------------------------------------------
> ```

Then, I wanna get results like this:

> ```
> ------------------------------------------
> id_iti | min | id_ciudad | max | id_ciudad
> ------------------------------------------
> 1      | 1   | 374       | 3   | 241      
> 2      | 1   | 34        | 4   | 17   
> ------------------------------------------
> ```

I need to show the max and the min value in the same row group by id_iti.
I have tried to use full join, but I'm working with sqlite, and that's not an option. I spend a long day trying with different options but I can't found the solution. I hope you guys can help me.
Thanks in advance!

Edit:

```
SELECT a.id_iti, c.id_ciudad, d.id_ciudad
FROM detalle_itinerario as a, 
(SELECT MAX(orden_iti),id_ciudad, id_iti FROM detalle_itinerario) AS c
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT MIN(orden_iti),id_ciudad, id_iti FROM detalle_itinerario) AS d
ON c.id_iti=d.id_iti
GROUP BY a.id_iti;
```

That's only one of my attempts, but I get just values of the first coincidence.

Comment: Please include what queries you have already tried in the question

Comment: Edited. I have another queries, but i guess that's the best query.

Comment: Is your sample right, should it not be 25 & 374 for the first row for min and max? Or do you want the first and last items from each order?

Comment: My sample is right. I want the first and the last item of each group, group by the column "orden_iti".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, use a simple query to get the min/max values for each group:

```
SELECT id_iti,
       MIN(orden_iti) AS min,
       MAX(orden_iti) AS max,
FROM detalle_itinerario
GROUP BY id_iti;
```

You can the use these values to join back to the original table:

```
SELECT a.id_iti,
       a.min,
       a2.id_ciudad,
       a.max,
       a3.id_ciudad
FROM (SELECT id_iti,
             MIN(orden_iti) AS min,
             MAX(orden_iti) AS max
      FROM detalle_itinerario
      GROUP BY id_iti) AS a
JOIN detalle_itinerario AS a2 ON a.id_iti = a2.id_iti AND a.min = a2.orden_iti
JOIN detalle_itinerario AS a3 ON a.id_iti = a3.id_iti AND a.max = a3.orden_iti;
```